# Arduino RGB component identification

Tags: components

[image: Arduino set RGB Component]

Can someone help me identify this component?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the purpose of identifying this product? Do you want to purchase one? Are you after the identification of the individual components or are you wanting the identity of the board?

Comment: It's an RGB led... connect GND to ground/0V and R, G or B to 5V to make the LED light up in that color?

Answer (score 2):

It's a common-cathode RGB LED module. The LED package itself has 3 independent LEDs, but the board ties the cathodes together.